# Jax-ws ignores custom exceptions

Tags: java, web-services, exception, wsdl, jax-ws

Some methods of my web service should returns custom exceptions to client. But jax-ws ignores declaration of custom exceptions during publishing of the endpoint.
Description of service and method looks like (implementation of this interface has the same annotation):

```
@WebService(name = "ContainerProxy")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ContainerProxy {

    @WebMethod
    public Response processRequest(Request request) throws
        BadRequestException, // Custom exception
        ApplicationNotFoundException, // Custom exception
        ClassNotFoundException,
        NoSuchMethodException,
        IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException;
}
```

The WSDL generated for this service looks like:

```
<?xml...
    <portType name="ContainerProxyImpl">
        <operation name="processRequest">
            <input wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequestRequest"
               message="tns:processRequest"></input>
            <output wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequestResponse"
                message="tns:processRequestResponse"></output>
            <fault message="tns:ClassNotFoundException" name="ClassNotFoundException"
               wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequest/Fault/ClassNotFoundException"></fault>
            <fault message="tns:NoSuchMethodException" name="NoSuchMethodException"
               wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequest/Fault/NoSuchMethodException"></fault>
            <fault message="tns:IllegalAccessException" name="IllegalAccessException"
               wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequest/Fault/IllegalAccessException"></fault>
            <fault message="tns:InvocationTargetException" name="InvocationTargetException"
               wsam:Action="http://proxy.container.hive.org/ContainerProxyImpl/processRequest/Fault/InvocationTargetException"></fault>
        </operation>
        ...
    </portType>
    ...
    <binding name="ContainerProxyImplPortBinding" type="tns:ContainerProxyImpl">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"></soap:binding>
        <operation name="processRequest">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </output>
            <fault name="ClassNotFoundException">
                <soap:fault name="ClassNotFoundException" use="literal"></soap:fault>
            </fault>
            <fault name="NoSuchMethodException">
                <soap:fault name="NoSuchMethodException" use="literal"></soap:fault>
            </fault>
            <fault name="IllegalAccessException">
                <soap:fault name="IllegalAccessException" use="literal"></soap:fault>
            </fault>
            <fault name="InvocationTargetException">
                <soap:fault name="InvocationTargetException" use="literal"></soap:fault>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        ...
```

So how can I return custom exception to a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that custom exceptions must be an extension of  class
`Exception` or other class which extends `Exception`. But I didn't knew about it and my custom exceptions was an extensions of `Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate the Web Service class with:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CustomWsName")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class WebServiceClass{

@WebMethod
..method...


}
```

Or with another SOAPBinding?

Comment: Try to use the SOAPBinding in my example for a test. In that way I can see the custom exceptions wrapped in the published wsdl.

Comment: Thanks fro your help. I've already found solution of this problem.